# Can not set ProxyWebsocketIdleTimeout

Tags: apache, websocket, proxy, timeout

I have a websocket proxy with httpd. I get the connection to the websocket but if the user does nothing for 60 seconds the connection gets terminated. I want to change this by setting "ProxyWebsocketIdleTimeout 120".

## access.log:

> my ip - - [01/Aug/2021:14:42:07 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36"
> my ip - - [01/Aug/2021:14:42:27 +0200] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
> my ip - - [01/Aug/2021:14:42:08 +0200] "GET /wss/ HTTP/1.1" 408 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36"

What I tried:
change httpd.config
TimeOut 600
ProxyTimeout 120
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 600

What I want to try:
ProxyWebsocketIdleTimeout 120

## apachectl configtest

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 16 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf:
> Invalid command 'ProxyWebsocketIdleTimeout', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

## httpd -M | grep wstunnel

proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)

## a2enmod mod_proxy_wstunnel

ERROR: Module mod_proxy_wstunnel does not exist!

## ls /etc/httpd/modules | grep wstunnel

mod_proxy_wstunnel.so

## httpd -v

Server version: Apache/2.4.48 (Unix)
Server built:   May 28 2021 16:40:47

How to activate ProxyWebsocketIdleTimeout?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am facing the same challenge. Dropping the connection after a few seconds of inactivity.

Comment: No. I switched to nginx.

Answer (score 0):

**ProxyWebsocketIdleTimeout** is only available in version **2.4.5 or greater**. You must upgrade your apache version (that you inform that is 2.4.48).

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html